# How to represent "{{" in a django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, tex, bibtex

I'm trying to output in bibtex format in Django and the template looks like this:

```
@{{ pubentry.type }{,
  author    = {{% for author in pubentry.authors.all %}{{ author.first_name }} {{ author.middle_name }} {{ author.last_name }}{% if not forloop.last %} and {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}},
  title     = {{{ pubentry.title }}},
  journal   = {{{ pubentry.journal }}}
}
```

The problem is with the `{{{` or `{{%`. One way to go around the problem is to add a space after the first `{`, but that kind of tamper the format. What's the right way to escape `{` in Django templates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the [*templatetag*](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) tag:

> Output one of the syntax characters used to compose template tags.
>
> Since the template system has **no concept of "escaping"**, to display one of the bits used in template tags, you must use the `{% templatetag %}` tag.

What you are after is:

```
{% templatetag openvariable %}
```

Maybe there is a nicer solution because this does not increase readability...

Answer (score 3):

Another (more flexible) approach may be to convert the values to a bibtex-like value before sending them to your template. You'll probably need to do this anyway to escape some of the characters that bibtex/latex can't handle. Here's something similar I prepared earlier:

```
import datetime

class BibTeXString(unicode):
  pass

def bibtex_repr(obj):
  """ A version of the string repr method, that always outputs variables suitable for BibTeX. """
  # If this has already been processed, it's ok
  if isinstance(obj, BibTeXString):
    return obj
  # Translate strings
  if isinstance(obj, basestring):
    value = unicode(obj).translate(CHAR_ESCAPES).strip()
    return BibTeXString('{%s}' % value)
  # Dates
  elif isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
    return BibTeXString('{%02d-%02d-%02d}' % (obj.year, obj.month, obj.day))
  # Integers
  if isinstance(obj, (int, long)):
    return BibTeXString(str(obj))
  else:
    return BibTeXString(repr(obj))


CHAR_ESCAPES = {
  ord(u'$'): u'\\$',
  ord(u'&'): u'\\&',
  ord(u'%'): u'\\%',
  ord(u'#'): u'\\#',
  ord(u'_'): u'\\_',
  ord(u'\u2018'): u'`',
  ord(u'\u2019'): u"'", 
  ord(u'\u201c'): u"``", 
  ord(u'\u201d'): u"''" ,
  ord(u'\u2014'): u'---', 
  ord(u'\u2013'): u'--',
}
```

You could even use this as a template filter if you wanted, making your template look like:

```
@{{ pubentry.type }{,
  author    = {% filter bibtex %}{% for author in pubentry.authors.all %}{{ author.first_name }} {{ author.middle_name }} {{ author.last_name }}{% if not forloop.last %} and {% endif %}{% endfor %}}{% endfilter %},
  title     = {{ pubentry.title|bibtex }},
  journal   = {{ pubentry.journal|bibtex }}
}
```

But I would escape the content before it gets to the template, so that your template just needs to do this:

```
@{{ pubentry.type }{,
  {% for field in fields %}{{ field }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
}
```

Or even leave out the template altogether at this stage. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Sounds interesting - I am still learning Django/Python (8 hrs of exp so far) but I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

With the [`templatetag`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) template tag.

```
title     = {% templatetag openvariable %}{% templatetag openbrace %} pubentry.title {% templatetag closevariable %}{% templatetag closebrace %},
```